# Erro em requisições com aiohttp em asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, assincronismo, concorrência, requisição

```
import time
import urllib.request
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URL = 'https://api.github.com/events'
MAX_CLIENTS = 10


def fetch_sync(pid):
    print('Fetch sync process {} started'.format(pid))
    start = time.time()
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    datetime = response.getheader('Date')

    print('Process {}: {}, took: {:.2f} seconds'.format(
        pid, datetime, time.time() - start))

    return datetime


async def fetch_async(pid):
    print('Fetch async process {} started'.format(pid))
    start = time.time()
    response = await aiohttp.request('GET', URL)
    datetime = response.headers.get('Date')

    print('Process {}: {}, took: {:.2f} seconds'.format(
        pid, datetime, time.time() - start))

    response.close()
    return datetime


def synchronous():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(1, MAX_CLIENTS + 1):
        fetch_sync(i)
    print("Process took: {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start))


async def asynchronous():
    start = time.time()
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(
        fetch_async(i)) for i in range(1, MAX_CLIENTS + 1)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print("Process took: {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start))


print('Synchronous:')
synchronous()

print('Asynchronous:')
ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ioloop.run_until_complete(asynchronous())
ioloop.close()
```

Estou estudando o módulo asyncIO do Python e me deparei com ese código no GitHub(https://github.com/yeraydiazdiaz/asyncio-ftwpd) mas o mesmo está gerando esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_one.py", line 198, in fetch_async
    response = await aiohttp.request('GET', URL)
TypeError: object _SessionRequestContextManager can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Não sei muito sobre o módulo ainda, alguém poderia me indicar o porque está ocorrendo esse erro e como posso fazer da forma correta.
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma maneira bem mais simples de se resolver isso. Primeiro, vamos definir uma função assíncrona que será responsável por fazer a requisição, utilizando o módulo `aiohttp`:

```
async def fetch(url):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
      return await response.json()
```

Basicamente a função define uma sessão, realiza uma requisição GET para a URL especificada e retorna a resposta decodificada como JSON. Com base nessa função, definimos a função que irá tratar das respostas obtidas:

```
async def get(url, name):
  print(f'Iniciando a requisição {name}')
  response = await fetch(url)
  print(f'Quantidade de eventos da requisição {name}:', len(response))
```

A função basicamente realiza a requisição, aguarda a resposta e exibe o número de registros que obteve na mesma. A mágica aqui acontece no *await*, pois durante a requisição HTTP, o interpretador do Python não precisa ficar travado para essa rotina, podendo ser direcionado às outras, fazendo todas as requisições em paralelo. Assim, vale lembrar que não é garantido a ordem que as requisições serão feitas.

Para utilizar a função `get`, podemos fazer:

```
requests = [get(URL, i) for i in range(MAX_CLIENTS)]
```

E devemos criar o laço de eventos para tratar de todas as requisições:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*requests))
```

Ficando, assim, o código final:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

URL = 'https://api.github.com/events'
MAX_CLIENTS = 10

async def fetch(url):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
      return await response.json()

async def get(url, name):
  print(f'Iniciando a requisição {name}')
  response = await fetch(url)
  print(f'Quantidade de eventos da requisição {name}:', len(response))

requests = [get(URL, i) for i in range(MAX_CLIENTS)]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*requests))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AquamarineInfatuatedTransfer)</sup>

Uma possível saída do programa é:

```
Iniciando a requisição 1
Iniciando a requisição 7
Iniciando a requisição 2
Iniciando a requisição 8
Iniciando a requisição 3
Iniciando a requisição 9
Iniciando a requisição 4
Iniciando a requisição 5
Iniciando a requisição 0
Iniciando a requisição 6
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 8: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 2: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 0: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 6: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 5: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 1: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 9: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 3: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 4: 30
Quantidade de eventos da requisição 7: 30
```

Comment: Saberia me dizer poque definir async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session, ou seja um gerenciador de contexto assincrono, qual sua utilidade no código ???