# Python iteradores, gerenciadores de contexto assíncronos

Tags: python-3.x

Estou estudando o módulo asyncio e aparecem algumas implementações de alguns outros serviços que entendo mas me peguei em algumas dúvidas, que seria iteradores e gerenciadores de contexto assíncronos.

Já vi códigos assim :

```
async def fetch(url):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
      return await response.json()
```

Aqui está o link da pergunta que fiz:

[Erro em requisições com aiohttp em asyncio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290697/erro-em-requisi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-com-aiohttp-em-asyncio)

Como é por trás dos panos o funcionamentos dos mesmos ???

Comment: Seria interessante você linkar a resposta onde este trecho de código está para contextualizar para quem não a viu.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado e desculpe